# How to update data from a radiobutton

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Hi i need some suggestions on how to retrieve data from a radiobutton. I have no problem on retrieving the id, course and year my only problem is the radiobutton.

Here is my sample code on retrieving the id, course and year. I need some help with radiobutton.

```
Private Sub GetRecord()


 Dim r As DataRow = Access.DBDT.Rows(CurrentRecord)


        txtStudID.Text = r("ID").ToString
        cbxCourse.SelectedItem = r("Course").ToString
        cbxYear.SelectedItem = r("Yr").ToString


End Sub
```

Code on inserting data to database:

```
Private Sub AddUser() 


        Dim TypeOfStudent As String

        If cbNew.Checked Then
            TypeOfStudent = cbNew.Text
        ElseIf cbOld.Checked Then
            TypeOfStudent = cbOld.Text
        Else
            TypeOfStudent = ""

        End If

        Access.AddParam("@ID", txtID.Text)
        Access.AddParam("@Course", cbxCourse.SelectedItem)
        Access.AddParam("@Yr", cbxYear.SelectedItem)
    Access.AddParam("@Type", TypeOfStudent)


Access.ExecQuery("INSERT INTO StudentInformation ( ID, Course, Yr,TypeOfStudent)
VALUES ( @ID, @Course,@Yr,@Type ) ; ")

 MsgBox("Student was added successfully.")
        Form1.RefreshGrid()
        Me.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the question. I don't see a radio button in your code...?

Comment: How is this different that [your last question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34271347/1070452) from yesterday?

Comment: Thats exactly my problem. I didn’t put any code of a radiobutton in the private sub getrecord() coz i dont have any idea on how to do it.

Comment: I think you must change question to : How bind data to radio button?

Answer (score 0):

I don'the understand exactly your question but if you want to bind data that you have retrieved from dB to radio button like AddUser method that you have get data you can set data to radio button :

```
Dim TypeOfStudent As String

TypeOfStudent = r("TypeOfStudent").ToString


    If TypeOfStudent == cbNew.Text Then
   cbNew.Checked =true

    ElseIf TypeOfStudent == cbOld.Text Then   
    cbOld.Checked =true
    End If
```